# How to get E-commerce transaction ID from Google Analytics tracker

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics.js

I'd like to know how to get the E-commerce transaction ID from a Google Analytics tracker object.

I already found the `tracker.get()` method: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers

By using `tracker.get('clientId')`, I successfully obtained the client ID from the Analytics tracker object.

According to the Analytics debug log, there is some transaction data stored in the Analytics tracker object with 'ec:id' as the transaction ID field. I tried to obtain the value of this field by using `tracker.get('ec:id')`, but this didn't return any result.

[image: Analytics debug log]

Comment: How this data is provided for the tracker itself? Isn't it available in a global variable, dataLayer, or URL parameter?

Comment: Hi @kgrg, the data is also available in URL parameters. These are placed between the parentheses (&ti).

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your tracker in the console. The following checks the first tracker, for example:

```
ga.getAll()[0];
```

Inspect the `data` field, then inspect the `keys` field. It'll be an array of what you can pass to a tracker's `.get()` method.

I suggest you try getting the `_ti` out of your tracker:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('_ti');
```

If it corresponds with the transaction ID, then I did not screw up.

Comment: Thank you Matvey for your quick response. I have tried to get the _ti out of the tracker. However, it returns '0'.

Comment: I see. On my end, it did return a much bigger number > 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the parameter by itself by using the ampersand syntax. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers#ampersand_syntax)

[Reference for field parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#(product_action)_id)

So for your case:

```
tracker.get('&ti')
```